# multiple @PersistenceContext unitname

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I had multiple unit name ,but according to user type wise i need to change unit name here how can i do in my  Data Access Object class class and it is extends Entity.please let me know if any possible.

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
```

protected EntityManager em;